# How to pass session on proxy with ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, session, express, nginx, proxy

My app is running on 3000 and I have set proxy to points 3000 from a subdomain name but the session is not working on proxy.

I have tried this:

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```

But it doesnt work.

Nginx config

```
listen 80;

server_name sub.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://domain.com:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Session config

```
app.use(session({
store: sessionStore,  //tell express to store session info in the Redis store
secret: 'mysecret',
key: 'emre',
saveUninitialized: false,
proxy: true,
resave: true,
maxAge: 60000
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? The cookie isn't getting forwarded through the proxy?

Comment: Yes can't access the session.

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple cookie-based session middleware.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.